# "404 not Found" with uWSGI integration with Ngnix Container

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to implement a basic flask application in a docker container which uses ngnix container for request/response with the help of uWSGI module in python.

But, I'm running into a pid error which I'm totally confused of and banging my head. Please take a look to the files below

**my flask application(run.py)**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Welcome to the site"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**my app.ini file for uWSGI**

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :8000
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

**my Ngnix conf file (default.conf)**

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /sample {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8000;
    }

}
```

> Note: `flask` is my container name and `/sample` is the page i want to reach which is flask ideally.
> **The error I run into while => curl http://localhost/sample**

```
flask  | [pid: 8|app: 0|req: 1/2] 172.23.0.1 () {32 vars in 343 bytes} [Tue Oct  4 03:00:29 2022] GET /thowbik => generated 207 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
nginx  | 172.23.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2022:03:00:29 +0000] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "curl/7.79.1" "-"
```

I checked all other setting, I hope, I did everything correct. While reaching `/` page it gives response nginx default page. but I cannot get response for `/sample`

For your Info https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVEjSmKFUVI, this is the tutorial I follow up to do.

Comment: If you are using any tutorial as base, please do share it so that people can have a complete idea of what you are trying.

Comment: All right, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVEjSmKFUVI thankss for the tip @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer for the above question !!, the `mount` option in `app.ini` file should be declared as `location`. Like, `mount = /sample=run.py` and I get the response from flask